# Bind9 custom rules no answer across subnets

Tags: networking, kubernetes, bind, internal-dns, traefik

I have a few different local subnets and some apps that I'd like to access with a custom DNS server. I have bind9 setup on 10.0.0.0 subnet and all of the devices on that subnet work as expected.

When I try an nslookup of one of the custom domains from a device on another subnet I receive `Can't find...: No answer`. The nslookup shows the server as the bind9 server (10.0.0.2) and query forwarding works, but the custom rules do not.

The bind9 server is running in a Kubernetes pod using traefik for ingress. This is the relevant config information for the bind9 pod:

```
- name: ALLOW_QUERY
  value: any
- name: ALLOW_RECURSION
  value: any
- name: ALLOW_QUERY_CACHE
  value: any
- name: DNS_A
  value: "*.mycustom.domain=10.0.0.8"
- name: DNS_FORWARDER
  value: "1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1"
```

I've tried checking firewall rules and everything seems right, which makes sense since forwarding is working as expected.